# When are temporaries created as part of a function call destroyed?

Tags: c++, memory-management, specifications

Is a temporary created as part of an argument to a function call guaranteed to stay around until the called function ends, even if the temporary isn't passed directly to the function?

There's virtually no chance that was coherent, so here's an example:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int x) : x(x) {printf("Constructed A(%d)\n", x);}
    ~A() {printf("Destroyed A\n");}

    int x;
    int* y() {return &x;}
};

void foo(int* bar) {
    printf("foo(): %d\n", *bar);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    foo(A(4).y());
}
```

If `A(4)` were passed directly to `foo` it would definitely not be destroyed until after the `foo` call ended, but instead I'm calling a method on the temporary and losing any reference to it. I would instinctively think the temporary `A` would be destroyed before `foo` even starts, but testing with GCC 4.3.4 shows it isn't; the output is:

> Constructed A(4)
>   foo(): 4
>   Destroyed A

The question is, **is GCC's behavior guaranteed by the spec**? Or is a compiler allowed to destroy the temporary `A` before the call to `foo`, invaliding the pointer to its member I'm using?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Temporary objects exist up until the end of the full expression in which they are created.

In your example, the `A` object created by `A(4)` will exist *at least* until the expression ends just after the return from the call to `foo()`.

This behavior is guaranteed by the language standard:

> Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created. This is true even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception (C++03 §12.2/3).

The lifetime of the temporary may be extended by binding a reference to it (in which case its lifetime is extended until the end of the lifetime of the reference), or by using it as an initializer in a constructor's initializer list (in which case its lifetime is extended until the object being constructed is fully constructed).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks to you and Jerry for finding the reference in the spec, I had trouble finding it

Answer (score 6):

§12.2/3: "Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created."

IOW, you're safe -- the `A` object must not be destroyed until after `foo` returns.

Answer (score 2):

The temporary lasts until the end of the expression it is part of - which in this case is a function call.

Answer (score -2):

The lifetime of your temp object `A(4)` will last long enough to call `y()`

The memory pointed to in the return of `y()` is not reliable, depending on threading and allocations it may be reallocated and the value changed before the call to `foo()` makes use of it.

Comment: Hmmm, apparently MSVC is giving me a non standard response, good to learn the standard.