# Passing a temporary object to std::cout

Tags: c++, temporary

I have this very simple piece of testing code:

```
std::string a = "A"
std::string b = "B"

std::cout << a + b << std::endl;
```

While it works in GNU g++, I'm worried if it is portable to pass the temporary `a + b` to `std::cout`, as in, is std::cout guaranteed to receive the correct piece of memory?

Many thanks!

Comment: @Mankarse, Yeah, it really is. I'll delete that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's safe. The temporary will not be destroyed until it has been processed by `cout`.

For more details, see [When are temporaries created as part of a function call destroyed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041249/when-are-temporaries-created-as-part-of-a-function-call-destroyed)

Comment: Yay, short and sweet. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes -- `a+b` creates a temporary `std::string` object, which gets passed to `std::cout`. At the end of the full expression in which it was created, that temporary object will be destroyed, but not before, so it'll remain valid until the end of the expression.

Other than that, the temporary is pretty much the same as almost any other `std::string` object, so the fact that it's a temporary object is irrelevant to how it's treated by `std::cout`.

Comment: Genuinely curious about this.: You said: "that temporary object *will* be destroyed" . Should that read: "that temporary object **can then** be destroyed" ? I'm not crystal clear on the standard on this (thus my question), but I was under the impression that the object doesn't *have* to be destroyed until the scope in which it operates is left, but is guaranteed NOT to be destroyed until the expression in which it participates is completed. It is really only important when dealing with predictable destruction within the current scope, but sometimes that is significant.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I don't have a copy of the standard handy to check right now, but *if memory serves* it's supposed to be destroyed before any subsequent expression is evaluated.

Comment: It peaked my interest so I looked it up, and you remember correctly. C++11 12.2.p3 specifies that "Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created. This is true even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception." It then goes on to specify the extension of object lifetimes (array constructions and destructions (p4) and references (p5)). Thanks for taking the time to point me in that direction.