# Don't call QString::operator[]() on temporary

Tags: c++, qt

I run [clazy](https://github.com/KDE/clazy) on my code and get warning about such code:

```
QChar value() const
{
    if (hide_content_)
        return '\0';
    else
        return text()[0];
}
```

where `text()` has such signature `QString text() const;`

warning is:

```
warning: Don't call QString::operator[]() on temporary
      [-Wclazy-detaching-temporary]
            return text()[0];
                   ^
```

But what does it mean? Is it possible that temporary `QString` object will be destroyed
before call to `operator[]`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is it possible that temporary QString object will be destroyed before call to  operator[]?

No, the warning is not about being an unsafe operation. Behavior here is completely defined as temporaries [aren't destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3041249/2666212) until the end of the full expression in which they are created (i.e. until the end of the `return` statement in your case).

**Summary:** The warning is about performance issues associated with the operation. You can fix it by using `.at(0)` instead of `.operator[](0)`. For an explanation continue reading the answer.

---

First of all, Qt's containers are [implicitly shared](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html); meaning that when you copy a container, its elements aren't actually copied until a write operation is performed on the container (aka. copy-on-write).

This means that the container needs to detach (perform a deep copy) whenever it detects a write operation, so that this implicit sharing remains transparent to the user.

And this includes cases when the container hands out non-const references to items inside it (exactly what non-const `operator[]` is doing), as it can't know in advance how you (the container user) will actually use these non-const references.

In other words, Let's say we have a `QString str = "abc";` when you write `QChar ch = str[0];`, `QString`'s non-const `operator[]` gets called and, to the container, this is exactly what it gets to know when a user writes `str[0] = 'x';`. This means that the container needs to detach whenever a non-const operation is called on it. It is the job of the user to use a const function when he/she isn't really going to change anything in the container.

Clazy here is trying to detect cases when users get a non-const reference inside a temporary (since it doesn't really make sense to mutate a temporary that is about to get destroyed soon).

---

**For more information:**

1. [Uncovering 32 Qt best practices at compile time with clazy](https://www.kdab.com/uncovering-32-qt-best-practices-compile-time-clazy/) - see #8
2. [Effective Qt - Marc Mutz - Meeting C++ 2015](https://youtu.be/Ov7s0GgBbOQ?t=1m17s)

Comment: Can you explain why the non-const operator[] would be called instead of the const operator[]?

Comment: @SteakOverflow, const `operator[]` is called only when using a const reference to the object, so as an alternative to the fix provided in the answer, one can use C++-17's [`std::as_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const) or Qt's [`qAsConst`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qAsConst) to get a const reference to the object.

Comment: @SteakOverflow, but that wouldn't work without some modifications to the code in the question, since `std::as_const` and `qAsConst` are deleted for rvalues.