# Are temporaries created as arguments in a call guaranteed to hold their lifetimes until the function call returns?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I need to return char arrays from a method `what()` to be used in `printf()` and variants.

The obvious solution of printing to a (thread local) static internal buffer obviously does not work because of the multiple calls problem.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

unsigned int counter = 1;

const char* what() {
   static char buf[8];
   buf[0] = counter % 10 + '0';
   buf[1] = '\0';
   counter += 1;
   return buf;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    printf( "%s %s\n", what(), what() );
}
```

Prints "2 2"  instead of "1 2".

```
$ g++ test.cpp -o test
$ ./test
 2 2
```

So I thought of creating a fixed size temporary buffer as in

```cpp
template <std::size_t N>
struct TinyString {
    char buf[N];
};
```

and implement the `what()` routine in a way that it returns a `TinyString` that will outlive the call.

```cpp
unsigned counter = 1;

TinyString<4> what() {
    TinyString<4> s;
    s.buf[0] = counter % 10 + '0';
    s.buf[1] = '\0';
    counter += 1;
    return s;
}
```

The call is similar

```cpp
int main() {
    printf( "%s %s\n", what().buf, what().buf );
}
```

When I run this code it produces the right results `1 2`

```cpp
$ g++ test2.cpp -o test2
$ ./test2
1 2
```

Now the question is if the two temporaries are guaranteed by the C++ standard to outlive the `printf()` call or it's UB in any way.

Comment: Just a point of clarification: `printf( "%s %s\n", what(), what() );` prints 2 2 because the values returned from `what()` are pointers to the exact same place. The order of `what()` s are unspecified but the result will be 2 2 regardless of order.

Comment: Yes they are guaranteed to live long enough. If that wasn't the case, you wouldn't be able to usefully return anything from any function, or indeed use any temporary.

Comment: Dup of [When are temporaries created as part of a function call destroyed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041249/when-are-temporaries-created-as-part-of-a-function-call-destroyed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's well-formed.

[[class.temporary]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#4)

> Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression ([[intro.execution]](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution)) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.

That means the two temporaries will be destroyed after the invocation of `printf` (immediately).